# Assign a float value to items in Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've looked around a bit and others threads on this kind of topic still aren't making a whole lot of sense to me.

I have a Spinner and items within that spinner. The items in that spinner are stored in a string array (stateNames) in strings.xml.

How can I make it so that each item within that spinner has its own float value? I want to do a different arithmetic operation based on what item is chosen in the spinner.

**For example:**

> Spinner item 1 has the value 1.2
>
> Spinner item 2 has the value 3.6
>
> Spinner item 3 has the value 7.31
>
> etc.

Here is my code for variable name references:

```
 stateSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.stateSelect);
    stateSpinnerAd = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.stateNames,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    stateSpinnerAd.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    stateSpinner.setAdapter(stateSpinnerAd);
    stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: if you are looking for a consistent solution you should create a custom adapter and do your logic there

Answer (score 0):

Create another array of floats that corresponds to the same positions in the text array identified by `R.array.stateNames`.

```
float[] floats = new float[] { 1.2f, 3.6f, 7.13f };
```

Then index into this new array when you receive the position of the selected item in onItemSelected().  You should take care to make this new array exactly the same length as the text array.

Comment: I'm pretty inexperienced, how would I go about indexing the float array?

Answer (score 0):

Spinners are ... special things... you need to get the parent.getId, this will tell you what was selected...and I have no idea how to get the ids without testing each of them, so i used toast.

```
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(parent.getId()){
                case 2131558516:
                       answer = 3.432;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + parent.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 234343243:
                       answer = 7.61;
                       break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Text of each item is the actual float value, then it will be much safer to use parse the Float string from the item's text, or from the original array.